# How to provide Qt installation path to configure?

Tags: linux, qt, makefile, configure

I got a source code from github. It writen by Qt, and I have installed the Qt from the Qt official website. But when I run `./configure`. It said `error: cannot find QtGui`. What can I do? I don't want to install duplicated through the `apt-get`. I set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in .zshrc. It's not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is to install dependencies through `apt-get`. If you install them manually, you need to resolve path issues by your own.

Since you've chosen the dark path, now you need to manually inform `configure` where your QT include files and libraries are located:

```
export CPPFLAGS='-I/qt/path/include'
export LDFLAGS='-L/qt/path/lib/'
./configure
```

One-liner:

```
env CPPFLAGS='-I/qt/path/include' LDFLAGS='-L/qt/path/lib/' ./configure
```

More info is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386315/how-to-add-libraries-path-to-the-configure-command).

Comment: Very useful! Thank u :)